# size of size_t compared to unsigned int

Tags: c++, c

Does anyone know any toolchain/platform/target combination where the maximum value of `size_t` is **smaller** than the maximum value of `unsigned int`?

I think both the C and C++ standards allow this in principle and it might (in theory) be useful on some wierd MCUs, but I've never seen this in practice.

*Note:*
I deliberately tagged this with both c and c++, as I'm interested in answers for both languages (if your answer is language specific, please say so) and I haven't yet seen any toolchain/target combination that uses different sizes for those types in c and c++ anyway.

Comment: I haven't yet had the pleasure of working on a machine with a 64 bit `int`. I'd conject though that your scenario would be common if 128 bit `int` ever becomes the norm, and the amount of memory available to a process doesn't allow you to allocate an array with size 2**128 (which to me seems likely).

Comment: @Bathsheba: Actually, ther are many embedded systems, where you won't be able to allocate UINT_MAX bytes, but usually size_t is still at least as big as unsigned int.

Comment: In practice, I believe your question boils down to: is there a 32 bit MCU with 16 bit address bus, or a 16 bit MCU with 8 bit address bus? Because that's the only system where the scenario from  your question makes sense. And no, I have never heard of such a MCU/DSP.

Comment: @Lundin: Actually, a segmented architecture like the 8086 allows for `size_t` values smaller than the address bus. `size_t` only needs to be large enough for the largest single object. But C++ in practice runs on unsegmented 32 bits systems, if not 64.

Comment: there are certainly systems with 16-bit size_t and 32-bit long ; I haven't encountered any with 32-bit int

Comment: @Bathsheba 64-bit-int? Hm, this might impose the necessity for a new `short short` type, otherwise we won't be able to provide all of 8, 16, and 32 bit data types any more...

Comment: As size_t is intended mainly for the indexing of arrays (though it is often used where ptr_t should have been used), it could easily be defined smaller in some of the 8086 segmented models supporting '386 instruction extensions, where the largest object that could be alloced was 64K, so size_t could be 16-bit, though the whole 640K was available for allocation, and the default integer size for '386 could be 32-bit. The '286 models could be used in a similar way, with up to 16MB (woo!) in 64K data segments. In both cases, pointers & ptr_t are actually 64-bit with segment and offset combined.

Comment: @GemTaylor Looking at the API design, it's *quite clearly* also intended for holding sizes of things. That is, if you don't mind me saying so, heavily implied by the name of the type ...

Comment: @unwind Reasonable. I would edit it more clearly but I've reached the character limit.

Comment: @GemTaylor: Intersting. Do you know if any compiler/toolchain actually did use a 16 bit size_t, but a 32 bit int when targeting some of those x86 chips?

Comment: @MSalters In my experience, segmented architectures rather tend to use larger pointers ("far pointers"), which would then mean a size_t which is at least as large as int. But all such systems, size_t tends to be the same size as int.

Comment: @MikeMB All old x86 compilers for MS DOS etc used 16 bit int iirc. And most likely size_t >= 16 bit.

Comment: There were certainly hybrid compilers that knew '386 but still could build for VM86 memory models, and there were numerous VM86 build modes with various compromises.

Comment: @Lundin most MCUs use Harvard architecture, so the data address bus will be different from the instruction address bus. For example 8051 has 8-bit data bus and 16-bit instruction bus

Comment: @phuclv I'm pretty sure that the 8 bit Harvards use 16 bit size_t and some other non-standard type in addition to it.

Comment: @Aconcagua Note that `(u)int8_t, (u)int16_t, (u)int32_t` are optional types on such a 64-bit only machine.  See §7.20.1.1 3 for details.  Further, `(u)int8_t, (u)int16_t, (u)int32_t`  can exist even if `short` is 64-bit on some unicorn machine.

Comment: It doesn't matter, and that's the whole point of having the type.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: It does matter when considering  data layouts.of aggregate types

Comment: @MikeMB: No it doesn't, because if you're mixing `unsigned int` and `size_t` and conditionally relying on them being the same type, you've already got it wrong.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Where did I say anything about relying on them being the same type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

H8/300 can be configured to. With GCC (configured with triple `h8300-elf` or `h8300-rtems`), this is the `-mint32` flag:

```
gcc/config/h8300/h8300.h:555:
#define SIZE_TYPE                               \
  (TARGET_H8300 || TARGET_NORMAL_MODE ? TARGET_INT32 ? "short unsigned int" : "unsigned int" : "long unsigned int")
```

So when `-mint32` is passed making 32-bit `int`, `size_t` is based on 16-bit `short`.

(Also note that, per comments in that file, GCC requires that `size_t` and `void *` must be the same size)

Comment: [Here is the gcc document](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3.5/gcc/H8_002f300-Options.html) and [here is the respective lines](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/config/h8300/h8300.h#L555)

Comment: Seems like a strange config for a 16 bit cpu but thank you very much. I'll see if any more answers come in soonish and otherwise accept yours.

Comment: @MikeMB there are no more solutions for GCC trunk: `rgrep 'define *SIZE_TYPE' gcc/config | grep -v '#define SIZE_TYPE "\(long \)\?unsigned int"'` ... the only interesting case is the (optional) 20-bit size_t on msp430, but it has 16-bit int.